# Qt: Как "grab"ить свёрнутый виджет?

Tags: qt, grab

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно получить контекст невидимого(свернутого) виджета, чтобы, в дальнейшем сохранить его в виде картинки?

Мне надо периодически захватывать содержимое виджета и сохранять его как изображение в формате PNG. Я это делаю это следующим образом:

```
QPixmap img = this->webWidget->grab();
img.save("image.PNG");
```

Всё бы ничего, но если окно приложения свёрнуто или данный виджет является ребёнком QStackWidget/QTabWidget, то на выхлопе получается пустое изображение с размером данного виджета.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, создать временный QWidget с атрибутами (Qt::WA_DontShowOnScreen | Qt::WA_AlwaysOnTop | Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating), и передать ему невидимый виджет.

Код можно посмотреть здесь: https://bitbucket.org/ioannsys/web2img/src/webbrowser.cpp (метод WebBrowser::TakeScreenShot()